# date difference using datepicker in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

Im trying to calculate the how many days there are between two dates and display the result in a textblock, i am using wpf. However i get a nullable object must have a value in the first line :S

```
    private void button20_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime start = datePicker1.DisplayDateStart.Value.Date;
        DateTime finish = datePicker2.DisplayDateStart.Value.Date;
        TimeSpan difference = start.Subtract(finish);
        textBlock10.Text = Convert.ToString(difference);
    }
```

Comment: I think you want `finish.Subtract(start)`, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message implies, `DisplayDateStart` is a nullable property, which means it can (and, by default, *does*) have no value. You have to handle this condition to produce sensible results.

That said, the `DisplayDateStart` property refers to the earliest date shown in the DatePicker's calendar, not the date the user has picked: for that, you need the `SelectedDate` property, which is also nullable.

There are a variety of ways you could handle a NULL value: display nothing in the TextBlock, display "N/A" or some other default, etc. Here's an example:

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This block sets the TextBlock to a sensible default if dates haven't been picked
    if(!datePicker1.SelectedDate.HasValue || !datePicker2.SelectedDate.HasValue)
    {
        textBlock10.Text = "Select dates";
        return;
    }

    // Because the nullable SelectedDate properties must have a value to reach this point, 
    // we can safely reference them - otherwise, these statements throw, as you've discovered.
    DateTime start = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
    DateTime finish = datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
    TimeSpan difference = finish.Subtract(start);
    textBlock10.Text = difference.TotalDays.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between  `SelectedDate` and `DisplayDate`? The latter is not nullable, so I thought it looked easier to use.

Comment: Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydate(v=vs.110).aspx), `DisplayDate` "allows the developer to specify a date to display if SelectedDate is null." It defaults to today's date, and I don't believe it necessarily represents the date the user has selected.

Comment: From MSDN: DisplayDate property affects the Calendar of the DatePicker.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(difference.TotalDays);` is a better output.

Comment: Ah, should've tested the formatting, and used the TotalDays property (but I still prefer to call the object's ToString() method directly). And as for `DisplayDate`: I can confirm it doesn't get updated with the date the user selects. If left unset, it retains today's date.

Comment: Ahh ok I will need to handle that somehow

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the selected date, you're using the wrong property. `DisplayDateStart` and `DisplayDateEnd` limits the possible choices. They are nullable because it should be possible to create a date picker without any limitations. Change your start and finish assignments to use the `DisplayDate` property instead:

```
DateTime start = datePicker1.DisplayDate.Date;
DateTime finish = datePicker2.DisplayDate.Date;
```

You should also consider renaming your datepickers. Having controls named `datePicker1` and `datePicker2` is typically hard to remember. What about `datePickerStart` and `datePickerEnd`?

(Disclaimer: I know that WPF controls typically don't get a name, because they are databound so the name won't matter, but in this case they are explicitly accessed and should have proper names).

Comment: I had originally tryed this but it out puts 00:00:00 to the textblock?

Comment: That's because by default the date pickers will display today's date. The difference between today and today is nothing. A zero `TimeSpan` will be formatted to 00:00:00. You have to call `difference.Format("d")` instead of `Convert.ToString(difference)` to output it as the number of days.