# Difference between two dates and put the result in IntegerUpDown field using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, date

I'm developing an app using WPF.
In one of my windows i have two date pickers and one IntegerUpDown field.
This is what i have ->
[image]

I want to change the value in the IntegerUpDown field according to the dates in the date pickers. For example, if the first date is 02-Sep-17 and the second is 07-Sep-17, the value should be 5.
I saw an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639516/date-difference-using-datepicker-in-wpf), but when i tried it, it had no result. The value was still 1.

I will appreciate any kind of help. :)

**Edit**
This is my code:
`DateTime dtDateCheckIn = dtpCheckIn.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
 DateTime dtDateCheckOut = dtpCheckOut.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
 TimeSpan difference = dtDateCheckOut.Subtract(dtDateCheckIn);`

**Edit 2**

```
public void ChangeNumberOfNights()
    {
        DateTime dtDateCheckIn = dtpCheckIn.DisplayDate.Date;
        DateTime dtDateCheckOut = dtpCheckOut.DisplayDate.Date;
        TimeSpan difference = dtDateCheckOut - dtDateCheckIn;

        numberOfNights.Value = difference.Days;
    }
```

The code is little different because i'm trying different ways to get the result and to put it in the IntegerUpDown field. I think that i miss something but i don't know what is it. :/

Comment: Show us code...

Comment: And how do you assign difference? You should probably take `difference.Days` and assign it to `IntegerUpDown` control.

Comment: I tried with `difference.TotalDays.ToString()` but with no result. I will try with your suggestion.

Comment: You won't be able to assign `string` to a control that manipulates `int`'s. Get number of days and assign it to `Value` of the control.

Comment: Yes, i know. I tried with `.Text` at first. That's why i used `.ToString()`.

Comment: I tried this -> `numberOfNights.Value = difference.Days;` but it didn't change the value of the IntegerUpDown field... Any suggestions? Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: You have to refresh ui. I don't know how to do this with `extended wpf toolkit`, but there should be a method such as `Refresh` or `ValueChanged`.

Comment: I'm using `SelectedDateChange` method but no result..

Comment: You have to refresh `IntegerUpDown` after you set new `Value`, so that the component knows that it has to be redrawn. Unfortunately I don't know what that method is called. You may want to try with something like `numberOfNights.Refresh()`

Comment: There is no need "refresh" the IntegerUpDown. Setting the Value property to an int value should work. Please post your exact code that doesn't work.

Comment: @mm8, I've posted the new code. This also doesn't work. :/

Comment: What calls `ChangeNumberOfNights()`? Does the user need to click a button in order for it to be called?

Comment: The function is called in method SelectedDateChanged of the two date pickers. I think that it might be in the wrong method but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example using the MVVM pattern.  I didn't have an Up/Down control handy, so I just used a plain `TextBox`, it should be fairly easy to replace.  It also uses the [AgentOctal.WpfLib Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgentOctal.WpfLib/1.0.30) (*disclaimer: this is a library that I maintain*) for the `ViewModel` base class, but this can be swapped out for virtual any other implementation, as long as it raises property change notifications.

[image]

Each `DatePicker` is bound to a `DateTime` field on the view-model.  When the setter is called, the `Difference` property (that is bound to the `TextBox`) is updated with the difference between the 2 dates.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm></local:MainWindowVm>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Date1}" />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Date2}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Difference}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindowVm.cs

```
using System;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib;

namespace WpfDates
{
    class MainWindowVm : ViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowVm()
        {
            Date1 = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
            Date2 = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
        }

        private DateTime _date1;
        public DateTime Date1
        {
            get { return _date1; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _date1, value);
                UpdateDifference();
            }
        }

        private DateTime _date2;
        public DateTime Date2
        {
            get { return _date2; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _date2, value);
                UpdateDifference();
            }
        }

        private int _difference;
        public int Difference
        {
            get { return _difference; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _difference, value);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDifference()
        {
            Difference = (int)Math.Floor((Date1 - Date2).TotalDays);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Bradley, I will check that. If i have a questions, can i ask you?

Comment: Sure! I'm happy to help.

Comment: Hey, Bradley. Can you send me an email at slav4eto95 (at) gmail (dot) com ? I have some questions about your example.